# Dynamically linked FFTW library to Qt5 Project fails when I build it

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator, fftw

**Details about my setup**: Using a Qt Mingw64 Build with .lib files for 64-bit machine generated per the FFTW instructions: http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html using  Visual Code 2019. Made sure to download the pre-compiled 64-bit DLLs to generate the .lib files.

This excerpt of the .pro file was generated by Qt Creator's Add Library tool:

```
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/fftw/ -llibfftw3f-3
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/fftw
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/fftw
```

In .CPP where I want to use FFTW library:

```
#include <fftw3.h>
```

What is in $$PWD/fftw:

- libfftw3f-3.lib
- libfftw3f-3.dll
- libfftw3f-3.def
- libfftw3f-3.esp
- fftw3.h
- Other misc. files included in FFTW 3.3.5 Precompiled DLL .zip

**Where it fails**: When I try to build it I get

```
 "error: undefined reference to `__imp_fftw_malloc'"
```

and more similar errors based on the methods I'm calling from the FFTW library but fails at build.

Qt Creator auto-completes the methods so it seems to be linking the FFTW library correctly.

Comment: Uh-uh. Unless I'm mistaken, that message is there telling you that the linking step has failed. The declaration of the function _is_ being found by the IDE in some header file. When it comes time to package it all up though, the linker can't find that function.

Comment: Sanity check: does the platform you're building for match the FFTW3 platform you downloaded? (x64)

Comment: @enhzflep The only reason I assumed the linking was successful was from reading "Qt Creator supports code completion and syntax highlighting for the added libraries once your project successfully builds and links to them." from https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html. Although it certainly doesn't build so you might be right in saying it might not be linking properly. Any ideas why the linker can't find the function?

Comment: @Botje Yes it is!

Comment: @RodolfoRodriguez - Sorry, it's been years since I did Windows dev and my tiny brain has forgotten some details. Lots of people have had _exactly_ the same issue that you have. (__imp_fftw_malloc is a good search term)